# Flask is raising "requests.exceptions.ConnectionError" when accessing non empty body of request in a docker container but not locally

Tags: python, docker, flask, request

I have the following endpoint in flask:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    d = flask.request.form
    return "200"
```

When running locally the following two requests return "200":

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/test"
non_empty_body = {"test": "2"}
empty_body = {}

response_1 = requests.request("POST", url, data=non_empty_body)
print(response_1.text)

response_2 = requests.request("POST", url, data=empty_body)
print(response_2.text)
```

when running in a docker container the second request (with the empty body) does also return "200" but the first request fails.  It gets stuck and after approx 1 minute it raises the following error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',
> RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

My Docker file looks as follows (leaving out a few lines that I am not comfortable sharing):

```
FROM python:3.7

ARG DEPLOY_TOKEN

# External dependencies

ENV WORKER_COUNT=2
ENV TASK_WORKER_COUNT=2
ENV SMART_ALERTS_WORKER_COUNT=5
ENV TASKS_CACHE_TTL_IN_DAYS=0
ENV TASKS_CACHE_TTL_IN_HOURS=4
ENV LOGLEVEL="INFO"

VOLUME ["/cache"]

EXPOSE 8080


# Install python and other tools
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        graphviz \
        fonts-freefont-ttf \
        fonts-roboto \
        gzip \
        curl \
        cron \
        dnsutils \
        iputils-ping \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*



ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade gunicorn cryptography \
    pandas==1.2.5 matplotlib numpy scikit-learn requests pytest flask pytz graphviz psutil prophet apscheduler
```

What is happening here and how to solve this? Obviously I need to be able to access the request body to handle post requests..